# Radxa Rock + ROS, how to install?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm new to microcontrollers and after taking a look around thought that the Radxa Rock looked like a good board to use for my Turtlebot2. From what I know so far, it dual boots Android and an Ubuntu variant I think is called Linaro. It's and ARM based board so do I just follow the ARM tutorial on the preinstalled Ubuntu or is there a better way (booting from MicroSD etc)?

I'm familiar with how to install and configure ROS on a regular Ubuntu install (Just installing indigo on Trusty on another PC) so just wondering if there's anything different that I need to be aware of.

Appreciate any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172647/radxa-rock-+-ros,-how-to-install?/) by [Praetorian](https://answers.ros.org/users/4747/praetorian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the most part, you should be able to follow the [Hydro UbuntuARM](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM) instructions.

If I remember properly, the Radxa has a fairly limited amount of internal flash storage, so to have enough space to install ROS I seem to remember having to repartition the internal flash and reimage the board. I know this required using Radxa's proprietary rkflashtool, but I can't seem to find the specific blog post I used as a reference. I remember hand-crafting a custom file that described the partition layout, and then pushing that to the board.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Cubie](https://answers.ros.org/users/18777/tom-cubie/) on 2014-06-03**:
The radxa rock has 8GB internal nand flash, 7G+ is for the linux rootfs. Download the server image here http://dl.radxa.com/rock/images/ubuntu/radxa_rock_ubuntu_server_140315_update.zip and flash it with rkflashtool.

**Comment by [Praetorian](https://answers.ros.org/users/4747/praetorian/) on 2014-06-03**:
Appreciate the advice ahendrix and Tom. I'll download the above and give it a go following the ARM instructions.

Will reflashing lose the Android partition? Don't really care either way, just want to know.

Cheers :)

**Comment by [Tom Cubie](https://answers.ros.org/users/18777/tom-cubie/) on 2014-06-03**:
I have created this page: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/RADXA
You can implement it after you have done it on RR.

**Comment by [Praetorian](https://answers.ros.org/users/4747/praetorian/) on 2014-06-03**:
Thanks Tom, above and beyond what I was expecting in terms of a response! I'll give it a go sometime this week and let you know how it went.